# How to add jQuery .on click to Tablesorter th?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, tablesorter

I have `table.tablesorter` element that change frequently using **AJAX**. I want to add event handler on 'click' that will delegate to `table.tablesorter th.class` element whenever I click its header. I'm new in use jQuery on. So, I try to put following jQuery script into Chrome Web Console.

jQuery script:

```
$('#table-content').on(
    'click', 
    '.tablesorter thead tr th', 
    function() {alert(); }
);
```

My HTML:

```
<div id="table-content">
    <table class="tablesorter">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="header">No.</th>
                <th class="header">Name</th>
                <th class="header">Phone</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

Result: there is no alert pop up window when I click header on the table.

What must I change to show alert dialog when I click the table's header?

Comment: Are you using any plugin? If that's the case, you need to apply on the generated HTML rather than the original markup...

Comment: I don't wanna touch the tablesorter plugin. Why jQuery .on not working in the generated HTML (`table.tablesorter`)?

Comment: I just made a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aakXC/ to test your code and an alert dialog shows up on my example when testing.  What's different from your code?

Comment: Can you make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with your code please?

Comment: That's all my code. Beside that, not so important, just code to load tablesorter script. Thanks for all of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ajax to load the table, I would recommend one of two things:

1. Only update the rows within the tbody, unless the header cells are completely being replaced, then you don't need to worry about dealing with the header clicks.

   If you have the tables stored as complete tables, then either follow the other option (recommendation #2), or load the table into a temporary holder, then transfer the tbody and update the table.

   ```
   var $table = $('#table-content').find('table');
   $('#hidden-div').load( "ajax.html", function() {
      // remove old tbody
      $table.find('tbody').remove();
      // move new tbody into the initialized tablesorter table
      $('#hidden-div').find('table tbody').appendTo( $table );
      // update tablesorter's cache
      $table.trigger('update');
   });
   ```
2. If the entire table is being replaced, just reinitialize tablesorter. Your ajax would look something like this:

   ```
   var options = { /* add tablesorter options here */ };

   $.ajax({
     url: url,
     data: data,
     success: function(data){
       $('#table-content').find('table').tablesorter(options);
     },
     dataType: dataType
   });
   ```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 <script>
 $( document ).ready(function() {
 $("table.tablesorter tr th.header" ).click(function() {
     alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
   });
  });
 </script>
 </head>

<body>
<div id="table-content">
  <table class="tablesorter">
     <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="header">No.</th>
            <th class="header">Name</th>
            <th class="header">Phone</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
 </table>
</div>
```

Comment: jQuery .click doesn't work with element that generated after DOM is complete, or for elements that created by javascript, if we just call .click function once after document ready.

Answer (score 0):

YOU Can try This Code

```
   $( "table.tablesorter tr th.header" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
  });
```

Comment: Would not recommend this if you are using ajax. The element might not exist when the event is bound. OP has it correct with `.on`